# Would it be possible to change the default values on a xbox 360 kinect?

Tags: windows, kinect, tracking

I got a kinect for 360 in hopes of using it in some projects regarding tracking and skeleton work, but I was stopped right on place because the kinect 360 does not have a near mode.

I'm pretty sure there's a way to force the kinect into a somewhat "near mode" by changing the default values for tracking distance, but I have no idea on where to change it or how, perhaps any of you could help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is a "near mode" for Kinect v1. The according property has to be set manually tho. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/kinect-1.8/hh855353(v=ieb.10))